# iPhone: Secure container

Tags: iphone, ios, security, webview

We're building an app that will download confidential PDF data. Once downloaded, it must be displayed securely. No copy/pasting allowed, or other ways of getting the data off the device. Eyes-only reading.

Is there a way to make the webView container act as such a secure container to display these PDFs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not 100% fool-proof in practice. You won't be able to prevent the user from taking a screenshot using the Home-Power button combination, or take a picture of the phone screen with another phone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can draw the PDF data onto a UIImage and display that. Also, just keep the data in memory and don't persist it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CGImageRef` in Quartz2D and create a UIImage with that representation, then use good 'ol `UIImagePNGRepresentation` on the created UIImage. Then, make sure you release all the objects in the `viewWillDisappear` or similar.